# Windows socket notification sink

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, sockets

What is the windows socket notification sink for? I am currently working with MFC socket and I think I have done something wrong since I get this message at windows shutdown. What could cause this?

Thank you.

Edit:
I am currently working with an application that needs to communicate via sockets. When I shutdown my computer I get a message box with a progress bar with the name of "windows socket notification sink". That's the much I can say about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An endpoint that you created was not properly closed. The Windows Socket Notification Sink is still running at shutdown because it believes it still needs to manage an endpoint.

Be sure you are properly disposing of all instances of socket classes that you create so that Windows cleans up and knows they no longer need to be managed. Which socket class are you using?

Comment: .net Socket on the C# side and MFC Socket on the C++ side.

Comment: Specifically the class names?

Answer (score 0):

What sink are you referring to?  What message?  You need to be more specific.