# Is it possible to suppress or redirect Windows Socket Notification Sink errors?

Tags: windows, sockets, error-handling, mfc, windows-server-2012

I did some googling on this and only found this link [Stack Overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034719/windows-socket-notification-sink) which discusses what causes the Socket Notification Sink error.

The application environment is currently Win2003/VS6.0/MFC/C++ we are migrating to Win2012/VS2013/C++/?MFC? (I use question marks as I am not directly involved in the GUI implementation and don't know the roadmap).

In my case I work with one or more applications that for some reason have crashed.  This will generate from 1 to 300 "Socket Notification Sink" dialog boxes that must be individually dismissed before recovery can begin.

I am looking for some recommendations:

1. Methods to clean up on crash to prevent the dialog from occurring.
2. Methods to instruct the Windows runtime to not generate a dialog box on
   error.  Redirect errors to a log or error console.
3. Method to dismiss all the error dialogs with one mouse click/Keystroke

Comment: I just found this which is a move in the right direction...
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/124873

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

Windows has a registry setting called error mode that controls how the system presents errors to the user.  You can use it to have the system skip popping up the dialog box and instead write the information to the event log.

See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254747/kill-error-process-if-it-appears-in-window-7-automatically/33260612#33260612).

You can also set ErrorMode for your program in code using the [SetErrorMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

This affects only your program.

Comment: Thanks, that's generally the route I was looking for, but I'm wondering if it can be done programaticlly.  (outside of the registry). Setting the registry might suppress other errors, I was hopping to suppress error dialogs from just within our application suite of tools.

Comment: You can definitely do it programatically.  It will only affect your program.  See the MSDN docs for [SetErrorMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621(v=vs.85).aspx)